# Твёрдое С или мягкая? — Твёрдый

Tags: фонетика, существительные, род

Почему не однозначно, то есть не единородно? Может быть, такое «разнообразие» — от облика буквы или звучания имени? Весь алфавит этому подвержен?

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря: 1. С [эс], неизм. 1. **ж. и ср**. Девятнадцатая буква русского алфавита, обозначающая согласный звук [с]. **Прописное С. Строчная с.**

Такая же информация дана для каждой буквы алфавита. Так что получается: А и Б  сидели на трубе, А —  ***упала/упало***,  Б —  ***пропала/пропало***. Кто остался на трубе?

Когда речь идет о написании букв, то удобно использовать оба варианта: ***Э оборотное/оборотная, И краткое/краткая.***

Но когда речь идет о буквах, обозначающих звуки, я предпочитаю говорить так: ***мягкий С*** (звук), ***мягкая С*** (буква).